# SharePoint document Hash value pair check with shared path document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have uploaded a document from shared path to SharePoint library.After uploaded a document I want o check the both the documents Hash Value .Is there any content is missed in the document or not. I used Hash algorithm byte array[] concept .
But this is working properly.it is working two file in the local path .

Has anyone tried this ?please share the link here...

Comment: The file format .txt and .doc is working when we use the hash algorithm ,but when we compare the .docx format files , I am getting mismatch error

Answer (score 0):

When you upload certain file types to SharePoint then the file contents is automatially changed. Just try uploading a small msg file. The msg file in SharePoint is different because SharePoint adds xsd schema information. This affects not only msg files but also Office files and tiff files. So if you try to calculate a hash of the original file and the uploaded file in SharePoint then in quite some cases they will differ.